# ClassLoader error when redeploy application

Tags: java, deployment, xpages, lotus-domino

I've a Java class in my domino project (in WebContent/WEB-INF/src) called by an XPages, that make a connection to a WebService through Axis (1.4)

Every time i update and save it, i need to restart HTTP, otherwise i have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.getResource(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.jdk.JDK12Hooks.getResources(JDK12Hooks.java:149)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResources(DiscoverResources.java:153)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.getNextResource(DiscoverResources.java:129)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.DiscoverResources$1.hasNext(DiscoverResources.java:116)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassNames(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:186)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.getNextClassName(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:170)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.DiscoverNamesInFile$1.hasNext(DiscoverNamesInFile.java:157)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.getNextIterator(NameDiscoverers.java:143)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.names.NameDiscoverers$1.hasNext(NameDiscoverers.java:126)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.getNextResource(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:159)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.resource.classes.ResourceClassDiscoverImpl$1.hasNext(ResourceClassDiscoverImpl.java:147)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder$1.run(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:120)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:113)
at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.newFactory(EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder.java:160)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getEngineConfiguration(Service.java:813)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
```

It's happen only on Lotus Domino Server for Windows, no matter with Linux release.
All jars are deployed on *lib/ext* folder, i've also included *commons-discovery-1.2.jar* in WEB-INF/lib of my project.
Any idea?

Comment: I forgot informations about environment: Lotus Domino 8.5.3 on Windows XP (found this article http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO66166 but doesn't work)

Comment: Consider switching to JAX-WS which comes with Java 1.6 and Domino.

Comment: FYI, this happen also in Lotus Domino 8.5.3 on Linux

Comment: Everything fine on Linux 8.5.1FP5